# Reading binary file in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I want to get access to binary file content pixel of image from ENVI logiciel :size (100*100) pixel coded each pixel in 16 bits in vhdl.

```
 library IEEE;
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
    Use ieee.numeric_bit.ALL;

    library std;
    use std.textio.all;

    entity image_bin is
    end entity;

    architecture behavioral of image_bin is
    type image is array(0 to 99,0 to 99) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal image(i,j):bit_vector(15 downto 0);

    begin
      process
      type t_file is file of bit_vector;
      file infile: text is in "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\file\T4.bin";
      variable pixel_image:bit_vector(15 downto 0);
         begin
         IF start'EVENT AND start = '1' THEN
         for i in to 99 loop
         for j in to 99 loop
         read(infile,pixel_image);
         image(i,j)<=pixel_image;
         end loop;
         end loop;
         file_close (infile);
         end if;
         end process;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working.

Comment: And ... is there a question?

Comment: thanks @DaveP and @ Brian Drummond , no there is no code yet but i want to know how i can get acces to binary file usong vhdl , some idea and advice   or any method to acces binary file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Thanks @DaveP, i want some idea howa i can read a binary file  content pixel image .i know the size of file and i know it coded each pixel in 16 bits .i dont know how i can get acces to this type of file because its difficult compare to txt file .i want some idea and some advice how i can programme to read binary file in  vhdl

Comment: Just google the keywords "vhdl read file". Please show that you made some effort.

Comment: i did that , and i wrote a code for txt file and its work now am asking how i can read binary file in vhdl ,i know that type of file is difficult to get acces in but im asking some idea  to wrote my code , thanks for your time @  JHBonarius

Comment: Then please show your code and what does not work. And show an example what you want. A [mcve].

Comment: i just do this code for reading a binary file and i have a lot of  errour

Comment: @DaveP  , i just did this code  and i have a lot of error so what i need idea from waht i write in the code howa i can read a binary file content pixel image and read them line per line , thanks a lot

Comment: @JHBonarius  , i just did this code  and i have a lot of error so what i need idea from waht i write in the code howa i can read a binary file content pixel image and read them line per line , thanks a lot

Comment: @JHBonarius  , i just did this code  and i have a lot of error so what i need idea from waht i write in the code howa i can read a binary file content pixel image and read them line per line , thanks a lot

Comment: Great that you added the code, now we can help you. However, I will go to sleep now (night in my country), so you'll have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: thanks a lot @JHBonarius ,ii well wait for you tomorrow for your advice and idea about my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [io - how to read image file and convert it to bits in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069105/how-to-read-image-file-and-convert-it-to-bits-in-vhdl)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Way before you start coding VHDL for an FPGA, especially complex algorithms, you should do two things:

- Learn basic VHDL
- Understand the capabilities of FPGAs

You can use file-I/O in VHDL to initialize FPGA memories (RAM/ROM) or in simulation constructs. But not in real-time data processing applications. As I say in the comments: A normal FPGA does not have file-I/O capabilities in a hardwired block. If you want something like this, it is probably best to use a microcontroller/CPU or us a SOC FPGA, which has a hard-wired ARM core on board and perform this in software. But when you're there, why use a an FPGA at all?

---

### Mistakes in your code

There are several programming mistakes in your code, which could have easily been prevented if you'd followed some tutorial.

With the first mistake, I am questioning if you have any programing experience. You define a type, and next you probably want define an object of that new type. But instead you type some illegal code:

```
signal image(i,j) : bit_vector(15 downto 0);
```

How would the parser know what `i` and `j` is? You don't define them until the declaration part of the code. Secondly, why are you suddenly using `bit_vector`, while you were using `std_logic_vector` just before?

Example of how it should be:

```
type [type name] is [type details];
signal [object name] : [type name] := [optional initialization details];
```

Next mistake: the process has no sensitivity list. A `process` statement is the start of a sequential processing block. Without any sensitivity list, it *automatically starts*. That's a problem: nothing blocks this, thus the process will try to loop infinitely within an infinitesimal time. This will of course cause problems. Solution: use the sensitivity list.

```
[label:] process ([trigger signal names])
begin
end process;
```

Internally the process actually has a trigger condition: `start'event and start='1'`... Where's this `start` coming from? Probably missing an input port on the entity? But this `start` should be the trigger for your process.

---

### How then?

What you *can* do, is read a file and initialize an array. (Please note that multi-dimensional arrays are not supported in synthesis, as there is no such thing as multi-dimensional RAM, so you will have to flatten your array and perform some index arithmetic). For the next example, I created a file "test.bin" and filled it with the string "12345678" = 8 characters = 8*8 bit = 256 bit = 2*2*16 bit -> good for a 2 by 2 array.

Then you should realize that the `textio` package can only read text! So the easiest is to read every 8 bits as a character and then concatenate two to form a 16-bit value.

Example code:

```
entity read_bin is end entity;

library ieee;

architecture behavioral of read_bin is
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    subtype data_type is std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    type two_dim_array_type is array(0 to 1, 0 to 1) of data_type;

    impure function init_two_dim_array return two_dim_array_type is
        use std.textio.all;
        type character_file is file of character;
        file file_pointer : character_file;
        variable upper : character;
        variable lower : character;
        variable output : two_dim_array_type;
        use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    begin
        file_open(file_pointer, "test.bin", READ_MODE);
        for i in 0 to 1 loop
            for j in 0 to 1 loop
                read(file_pointer, upper); -- first 8 bits
                read(file_pointer, lower); -- second 8 bits
                output(i, j) := 
                    std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(character'pos(upper),8))&
                    std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(character'pos(lower),8));
            end loop;
        end loop;
        file_close(file_pointer);
        return output;
    end function;

    signal two_dim_array : two_dim_array_type := init_two_dim_array;
begin
end architecture;
```

Voila:

[image: Modelsim output]

---

### The big question

The big question for me is: how come you get a PhD position in telecommunication and embedded system when you make these programming mistakes? Or lacking knowledge om the capabilities of FPGAs. I'm a PhD candidate Electrical Engineering myself and this is stuff we teach our first-year bachelors students. When I wanted my PhD position, I went through a few rounds of assessments, where my knowledge was extensively tested. There's a lot of competition going on for these positions.

My advice: Please get some local support for realizing this. You don't want to spend the next 3 years of your PhD trying to learn VHDL to an adequate level and then finding out you only have 1 year to do some actual research to be able to publish results...

Comment: an [ENVI Image File](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/ENVIImageFiles.html) is a flant binary file with an accompanying [ASCII Header File](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/enviheaderfiles.html) describing the format of the flat binary file. Neither of which your *accepted* solution attempt to read. Most peculiar particular, after having been berated  as a PhD in your answer and comment to his question he asked again in a new question.

Comment: @user1155120 I don't have time to do all his work for him. But feel free to come with a better answer.

Comment: @JHBonarius thanks for your your time and your answer ,first  dont have lot of experience in programming with VHDL , that why  i have difficult to read binary file , seconde i will take you answer and you idea to  read my binary file . just i want to clear ,So in  the programme i can read my binary file in character the first 8 bits as a character  and the second 8 bit as a character then we transforme to one line content 16 bits (2 char=16 bits)

Comment: @elmakhloufiassaad yes, read two 8-bit characters, convert them to a `std_logic_vector` (via `unsigned`) and concatenate them. Another tip: probably your university has some lectures in VHDL/MATLAB/Python/C++, so you can get some experience in labs. I would really advise you to join these asap. You really want to plan and do things efficiently when doing a PhD, or you'll run out of time in the end.

Comment: @ JHBonarius thankyou for you clarify , i will start programming  and take your idea and answer in my first priority. just another question if that possible : All binary type can be read like you told mee because my file its a raster file but without header ?

Comment: @elmakhloufiassaad See user1155120's comment to my answer: ENVI image file is something special. Binary just means it's '0's and '1's. But sometimes the data is 8 bit, sometimes 16 bit, etc.. or it's even variable bit rate! And sometimes the data is unsigned, sometimes signed. Or even fixed-point, floating point... and that could be standardized or custom format. And seeing you want to read a 2D array: it the data ordered column-first or row-first? I think you should write an algorithm in Python or MATLAB first. That way you can easily visualize the data.

Comment: @JHBonarius is ee, the data are 16 bits unsigned and each line is a pixel coded in 16 bits , and the size of is 100*100 pixel .

Comment: @elmakhloufiassaad It doesn't matter what the data is. You asked "All binary type can be read [...]?". My answer is "no", because 'all binary type' can be everything....

Comment: @JHBonarius thankyou for your clarify , So in your experience can i  read a binary file  in "MATlab"  ? (without the header)

Answer (score 0):

Question is far too unspecific but here are  a couple of pointers.

Binary file I/O works in VHDL but is only guaranteed to be compatible with itself, i.e. you can read files your simulation originally wrote. Beyond that, you may need to experiment.

I've read 3rd party files in Modelsim with little in the way of surprises, (possibly unexpected endian-ness, I can't remember) and I expect GHDL would also work well.

However, Xilinx ISIM (in the ISE10.1 era) insisted on seeing a specific binary header on each file, whose format Xilinx refused to document even when explicitly asked.

I wrote a file from ISIM, inspected its contents, and hacked that file's header onto the image files I needed to read, and stripped it off any further output files, using the Linux `head` and `tail` commands, so I could interchange binary files with the rest of the world. ISIM was perfectly happy with that, but it was a pain.

---

EDIT now we have some code ...

First, there is nothing wrong with doing this in VHDL as opposed to Python; there will be a bit more typing involved (in both senses of typing) but whichever language you use, you will have to understand what you are writing.

And you will have to finish the code (some of it is missing) and fix the trivial mistakes (you have a type and a signal with the same name ... sloppy practice in any language) and other trivial syntax errors.

So the next step is to finish it, compile it, and fix those errors. If you don't understand the errors after double checking the erroneous line against your VHDL textbooks, post the error message and ask what it means and what to do about it - at least, that would be an actual question.

You are also using VHDL-1987 file declarations and declaring the file of type text; you'll have to upgrade to VHDL-1993 file handling. It shouldn't be difficult to find examples of "VHDL-1993 binary file I/O" by the usual methods - try it.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Drummond, i want to get acces to this type of file because im work now on my phd and satellite image using ENVI logiciel .this logiciel give me image in binary file so i want to get acces in this file and readed ana modify the content .so i want to use VHDL to get acces and i want some idea  and advice to start programme the architecture

Comment: @elmakhloufiassaad why IHN do you want to use VHDL for this?! As an experiment to learn vhdlI would understand, but you seem to want to use it for a professional application. Why not use Python I.e.?

Comment: @ JHBonarius  i want to use VHDL in my research phd because my theses about fpga implementtation of algorithm of remte sensing , so the information enter to fpga is binary  file , so i want to gat acces to thbis file for modify  the pixel there and  i dont know how to programmme with python.

Comment: @elmakhloufiassaad wow... for your PhD? What department? You should really start talking to some people in your electrical engineering/embedded systems department. This file I/O VHDL code is **NOT** synthesize. How do you plan to get the file into the FPGA? Connect a disk-drive to the pins and hope that it works?

Comment: @ JHBonarius  my department  telecommunication and embeded system,"RS&GIS  Lab".the first steps to accelerate in my phd is to get acces to binary file this the keys or first key of keys .so we work with ENVI logiciel ,the reception of the image is in the form of a binary file.so first step that told me my framing is to get acces to binary file using vhdl and get acces to each pixel in the file .

Comment: @Brian Drummond thanks or your  advice and idea , i will correct the error in my code and take a look of  "VHDL-1993 binary file I/O" by the usual methods.